# PyInstaller ImportError

Tags: pyinstaller

I have been experimenting with PyInstaller for a few days. My operating system is FreeBSD 10.4 and I use Python 3.6. When I issue this command from the terminal, it works all fine:

```
# pyinstaller my_script.py
```

But this command has an unprecedented side effect. When I write this:

```
if __debug__:
  print("debug")
```

I get "debug" printed to the console, which suggests that PyInstaller compiles the script with debug symbols.

While searching for a solution to this problem, I found that running PyInstaller through the Python interpreter with the -O parameter would solve the problem:

```
[root@bsd-pwb ~]# /usr/local/bin/python3.6 /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py my_script.py
```

But this time, I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from . import __version__
ImportError: cannot import name '__version__'
```

What am I doing wrong here? How can I get PyInstaller to compile with "**debug**" set to "False"?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you trying your script exactly as it is but using a Python 3.5 Enviroment, there are so many publications where you can realize that pyinstaller is more stable with python 3.5 versions than 3.6. I had several errors as the one you are commenting and at the end they get solved just running my scripts on python<=3.5

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#running-pyinstaller-from-python-code) you can actually get it working by using another method: set explicitely the `PYTHONOPTIMIZE` environment variable to a non-zero value, in your case:

```
PYTHONOPTIMIZE=1 pyinstaller myscript.py
```