# pyinstaller gives "ImportError: DLL load failed"

Tags: python, bluetooth, pyinstaller

When I run my program that I compiled from python to exe with pyinstaller it gives an error (I use python 2.7.16):

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bloepie.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\users\stefan\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-v9ecuy\pyinstaller\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 395, in load_module
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\bluetooth\__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
  File "c:\users\stefan\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-v9ecuy\pyinstaller\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 395, in load_module
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\bluetooth\msbt.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "c:\users\stefan\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-v9ecuy\pyinstaller\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 395, in load_module
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\bluetooth\_msbt.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\bluetooth\_msbt.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
[21200] Failed to execute script bloepie
```

I compiled it with:

```
pyinstaller bloepie.py --onefile
```

[this person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50275777/pyinstaller-importerror) had the same problem as me but the only answer he got was that he should upgrade to python 3 or higher which I don't want to do and it wasn't marked as correct answer so I also have no guarantee that if I did it it would work. This person has a slightly different issue though. I have a "Import error: DLL failed to load: ..." he has a normal Import error (I don't know if this makes a difference but I couldn't find anything about it)

Here is the python code I compiled with pyinstaller:

```py
import bluetooth
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller

mouse = Controller()
may_i = 0
may_x = 0
may_y = 0
lockdown = 0

server_sock = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
server_sock.bind(("",bluetooth.PORT_ANY))
server_sock.listen(1)

bluetooth.advertise_service(server_sock, "helloService",
                     service_classes=[bluetooth.SERIAL_PORT_CLASS],
                     profiles=[bluetooth.SERIAL_PORT_PROFILE])

client_sock, address = server_sock.accept()
print "Accepted connection from ",address

while True:
    may_i = 0
    gata = client_sock.recv(1024)
    if gata == "":
        break
    data = gata.split(";")
    for dt in data:
        if dt == "":
            may_i = 1
        if dt == "Down":
            loci = mouse.position
            may_x = 0
            may_y = 0
            lockdown = 0
            may_i = 1
        if dt == "Up":
            if may_x == 1 and may_y == 1 and lockdown == 0:
                mouse.press(Button.left)
                mouse.release(Button.left)
            may_i = 1
        if may_i == 0:
            print "received: %s" % dt
            if dt == "x0.0":
                may_x = 1
            if dt == "y0.0":
                may_y = 1
            if dt != "x0.0" and dt != "y0.0":
                lockdown = 1
                if "x" in dt:
                    dt = dt.replace("x", "")
                    if "-" in dt:
                        dt = dt.replace("-", "")
                        if dt.split(".")[0] != 0:
                            dt = str(float(dt) * 1.5)
                            mouse.position = (mouse.position[0] + int(dt.split(".")[0]), mouse.position[1])
                    else:
                        if dt.split(".")[0] != 0:
                            dt = str(float(dt) * 1.5)
                            mouse.position = (mouse.position[0] - int(dt.split(".")[0]), mouse.position[1])
                if "y" in dt:
                    dt = dt.replace("y", "")
                    if "-" in dt:
                        dt = dt.replace("-", "")
                        if dt.split(".")[0] != 0:
                            dt = str(float(dt) * 1.5)
                            mouse.position = (mouse.position[0], mouse.position[1] + int(dt.split(".")[0]))
                    else:
                        if dt.split(".")[0] != 0:
                            dt = str(float(dt) * 1.5)
                            mouse.position = (mouse.position[0], mouse.position[1] - int(dt.split(".")[0]))
                        
client_sock.close()
server_sock.close()
```

So what is going wrong here? Why isn't the compiled version running? (the py file works fine)
Thanks

Comment: ***"ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found."***. The message say it all. You have to force `pyinstaller` to add the missing `DLL`!

Comment: _I have a "Import error: DLL failed to load: ..."_ as I said I knew that I just need to know what DLL and how to add the missing DLL

Answer (score 3):

I have tried using hooks but it didn't work well for my code. Instead, I copy the whole scipy folder to the python code folder and the issue was fixed. In my computer, the scipy folder is in `"D:\Programe\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages"`.

Wish it can help you.

**In summary, my tips in package using pyinstaller shows below:**

1. Need add following code in the beginning of spec file:

> ```
> import sys  
> sys.setrecursionlimit(5000)
> ```

2. Copy high-risk modules to the packaging folder to avoid DLL missing error. (In my work, Numpy, Scipy and Pandas are copied.)
3. For other error like module missing, you can fix the error by add the module in hiddenimports of the spec file.
4. Need update Pandas to 1.x.x version. Pandas 0.24.x version will show "No module named 'pandas._libs.tslib'" and cannot be fixed by hiddenimports.

Answer (score 0):

In order to force pyinstaller to add the missing dll, you can add a [binary hook](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/hooks.html#hook-global-variables) in your spec file. The spec file is created by pyinstaller in order to describe how your program is build. But when there is some `dll`, they cannot be found by only analyse your code, thus you have to edit this file (more information about this file in the [documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/spec-files.html)).

After a first, run, you can edit this file and add a line looking like the following one in the `Analysis` part. I edited the example from the documentation with a fake dll:

```py
a = Analysis(['minimal.py'],
     pathex=['/Developer/PItests/minimal'],
     binaries = [ ('C:\\path\\to\\the\\wbtapi.dll', 'dlls') ],
     datas=None,
     hiddenimports=[],
     hookspath=None,
     runtime_hooks=None,
     excludes=None,
     cipher=block_cipher)
```

But without the package name, I cannot be more precise.

**Edit**: with pybluez for win10, I think you have to find the `wbtapi.dll`. I don't have windows 10 thus I can't know where it can be.

**Edit bis**: more explanation.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention what bluetooth module. its ```pybluez-win10==0.22```

Comment: Please, edit your answer and make it a bit more descriptive by adding where the `biniaries = ` have to be added and how the `spec file` are used in the `pyinstaller ...` command line.

Comment: where can I find the ```wbtapi.dll```? I searched my python27 folder but couldnt find it

Comment: I don't know. Did you install anything else for pybluez? Have you search in your program file folders?

Comment: I've searched my entire C drive (I have python installed on my D drive but I searched the folder "Python27" on there) but couldnt find it. I didnt install anything else for pybluez I just installed it with pip

Comment: Did you use virtual environment? Or a conda one? The package `pybluez-win10` installed with pip comes with `c`, `cpp` and `h` files which are compiled when you installed the package.

Comment: @ndclt I installed it with pip (I said that in the question) but what do those files have to do with finding that dll that I have to include?

Comment: As you have not install anything else for bluetooth, I think the dll is built from the previous files. Maybe the name of the dll is wrong. Did you have any dlls in your site-package folder which is in the Python27 folder?

Comment: I dont have any dll's directly in my site-packages folder but I did have some in subfolders: https://ibb.co/gwKxP8P @ndclt

Comment: In the created file (which is a zip with a different extension), is there any of the dll missing? If some are missing, you should try to add them all.

Comment: @ndclt How do I know if there's one missing? And what do I do if there is one missing? Where do I get the missing dll?

Comment: I think I know what dll is missing I think its bthprops.cpl. Pybluez uses Irprops but it isnt present on the newer versions of windows 10. But where can I find this dll? link: https://www.bountysource.com/issues/65165541-dll-load-error-when-importing-on-newer-version-of-windows-10-due-to-missing-dependency)

Comment: Apparantly I do need wbtapi.dll and its supposed to be in my system32 folder but it isnt there. I dont want to download it from a site because I dont want a virus any tips?

Comment: I think the dll is on your system because the script works uncompiled and the script also need the dll. You should search into your Path and Python path.

Comment: Yeah thats what I thought to, but like I said I've searched my entire C drive and my python27 folder but I didnt find any file called wbtapi.dll

Comment: I downloaded listdlls and listed the dlls when I ran the script with python and listed the dlls when I put a try and except in the script when I compiled it with pyinstaller and the dll that I could see wasnt imported between the two was "irprops.cpl" in my system32 folder. but when I try to add-data or add-binary this file with pyinstaller I get this error: "pyinstaller: error: argument --add-data: invalid add_data_or_binary value: 'irprops.cpl'"

Comment: Can you edit your initial post with the full command line and the full error? Did you write the absolute path to the `irprops.cpl` file?